# ASP.NET MVC3 Validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

If you go to this website, http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3, you can see a tutorial where users create a movie database. I completed this tutorial with no problems, and attempted to create a new MVC application with some small changes that make the project more similar to what I want to do eventually.

Rather that create a model named Movie, I created one named Issue. Like movie, it has a few fields, but they are all different names and types. I went through the process exactly as is done in the tutorial, but whenever I try to add an issue to the database via the web UI, I get a DBEntityValidationException. I have not set any validation rules at this point in the process, so I am unsure of what the problem is.

Can someone give me some advice on fixing this so that I can add Issues to my database (as is done with movies on the online tutorial)?
Let me know if more information is needed; I am very new to this and may be lacking in details.

Here is the model code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcApplication200.Models
{
    public class Issue
    {
        public String id { get; set; }
        public DateTime created { get; set; }
        public DateTime closed { get; set; }
        public String summary { get; set; }
        public bool? importToTFS { get; set; }
    }

    public class IssueDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Issue> Issues { get; set; }
    }   
}
```

**Update:I just redid the whole process, but rather than have different fields and different types, I made it so that my Issue model had the same number and same types of fields (with only different names). The error went away, so the problem must be with db format or something. I hope this makes the problem more clear.**

Comment: Please post your model code! Without it, it's going to be nearly impossible to help you with this.

Comment: How was the database created?  Does it have constraints that the sample didn't that aren't being met? Are you using Entity Framework with Code First?  Database First?  Model First?  Definitely need more info.

Comment: I posted to model code. The database was created, as far as I can tell, when I created a controller for the model named Issue. This link is the page where I got my instructions from: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller

Comment: @C.Williamson is the posted model the cut down one mentioned in your Update?

Comment: Add this as an answer then @C.Williamson :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up adding this class, which removes everything from the database when fields are changed. Then, I refresh the database, which is easy to do in my situation. One could add some items to the Seed method in order to ensure that some things remain in the updated database after it is cleared.

```
public class IssueInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<IssueDBContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(IssueDBContext context)
    {
        //add things here
    }
}
```